# Delegate attach on a non event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript applying changes to some elements and a function loading more of such elements.
Like that:

```
<ol id="test"><li>click</li></ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('OL').delegate("li","click",function(){
        $('#test').append('<li>click</li>');
    });
</script>
```

This is the basic functionality of delegate and it works.  I can click on multiple `<li>` elements.

The problem is that i want to, **additonaly** do the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').css('color','red'); 
    //this is just an example, I don't need to paint the text red :)
});
```

for all `li` not just the ones that are loaded at the page load.

I haven't been able to attach those changes to anything (there is no event that indicates that I have loaded the elements in the append above).
Also I know I could recall `$('li').css('color','red');` every time I call the append (or on ajax callbacks which are the thing I'm really working). But I have a system with a lot of ajax calls that return different HTMLs and a lot of pluggins and jquery staff that needs to be executed against this elements. I don't want to do a giant "refresh" function to be called on every ajax success.

Right now the only solution I find is to bind everything to an arbitrary event and do a trigger call for that event on every ajax load like that:

```
<ol id="test"><li>click</li></ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('OL').delegate("li","click",function(){
            $('#test').append('<li>click</li>');
            $('#test').children().trigger('load');
        });
</script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('OL').delegate("li","load",function(){
            $(this).css('color','red');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works for all elements loaded *afer* the first. So I would need some extra code but it *works*.

Does anybody have any better solution?
Any way to do a "live" for non events?

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
Regarding the "red" example in the code... the changes I need to do are those amongst many others:

```
('BODY').delegate(".mcs_container","load",function(){
        $(this).mCustomScrollbar("vertical",400,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","no","no",0);
    }).trigger('load');
```

So I think only triggering a function will work.

**EDIT 2**
I've created a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/THHNS/5/
What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to avoid the extra trigger `$('LI').trigger('focus');`

**EDIT 3**
I was using delegate when ON should be enough and better.
The updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/THHNS/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that is not possible to atach live function calls to something that is not an event.
The best solution I've find that works is the following.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on("click","li", function(){
            //this click simulates an ajax call
            //the html appendend is generated and can have a lot of elements that need javascript work

            //this simmulates the html append
            $('#test').append('<li>click</li>');

            //in my proposed solution the function that attachs the HTML will recur all children of the attached element and trigger a custom event
            $('#test').children().trigger("myLoaded");
        });

        //all jquery functions that usually are called like:
        //$('LI').css('color','red');
        //are called inside the focus event
        //this functions could be anywhere and I don't need to know them prior to the ajax load        
        $(document).on("myLoaded","li", function(){             
            $(this).css('color','red');
        }); //(note 1)

        //Trigger the custom event once to paint red the first element
        $('LI').trigger('myLoaded'); //(note 2)
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="test"><li>click</li></ol>
</body>
```

You can try it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/THHNS/33/

@charlietfl suggested that one could chain the trigger in (note 2) chained to the declaration in (note 1) but I haven't been able to make it work.
I'm sure it can be done with less lines anyway. But I guess this solution will suffice to keep my code organized in the one page full ajax loads project I'm working.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

It's not better do define a class?

```
.myredclass {color: red;}
```

And add it on creation of LI's:

```
$('#test').append('<li class=\"myredclass\">click</li>');
```

I bet it would be much more fast.

Obviously it depends on how dynamic your css styling must be (if you want to set a different x offset for every LI it's not a feasible solition, but for simple and consistenti stiling you might do this way).

Comment: Please, Cranio, could you please read the question carefully *before* giving an answer?
As I said:
//this is just an example, I don't need to paint the text red :)

What i need to do is not to change the style. That was just a simplified example.

Thanks.

Comment: I have read you question **very well**, @Hanoc, there's no need to be on the verge of rudeness to one who takes its time to help you. I guess you have not considered the possibility that someone could have understood "he doesn't need to make `color: red` but *maybe* other css transformations?".
By the way, I have *clearly* stated in my answer that the solution would depend on how "dynamic" the changes would be, and that for a simple CSS application my answer is ok, for complex and variable tasks (different CSS to elements, but it could be extended to various types of changes) it was not.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you really didn't read my full post because I assumed my explanation was enough. It wasn't, my fault. (my previous apologies got lost. I hope I doesn't repost them)

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve all of your dilemmas, but once you create a custom event  you can also trigger it immediately in the same chain allowing you to do a simple setup for plugins that activates on page load and is ready for use in ajax success

```
   $('OL').delegate("li","load",function(){
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }).trigger('load');
```

Comment: That is cleaner than my solution. I'm beginning to think that the solution I seek does not exist but I'll wait a little before approving your answer. I can't vote up for lack of reputation but thanks for the hint anyway!

Comment: try setting up different "actions" that you can pass right from a click event, to a master ajax calling function, and then to a master ajax success function. Between 2 params like action and whatGetsChanged you can do quite a bit of organizing in master ajax handling functions, adding in of course other data that relates to each transaction

Comment: a list of typical CRUD actions can  start branching your code quite a bit  `{action: 'edit', whatToChange: 'myTable', dataToServer:{....}}`. I do this in all event handlers in heavy ajax pages and pass them to master ajax handler, which uses master callback handler as much as possible

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. I do that. I stripped that from my example. I do that with all callbacks related to the load but the effects I'm trying to discociate from my ajax are those not related to the load of certain elements like javascript beautifications or "standard" replacements. For example the replacement of a custom scrollbar for a JS one. Of course one could say that *that* is associated with the load. Anyway, just trying to organize things. Thanks!

Comment: understand...it gets ugly sometimes now matter how organized you try to get it. Can also pass data into the custome events if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(document).on("click","li", function(){
                $('#test li:first-child').clone().appendTo('#test');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="test"><li style="color:red">click</li></ol>
</body>
```

Comment: It works on the example but it will not work in my case. I'll need to load dynamic content, not just duplicate. Nice lateral thinking anyway! thanks!